# jquery trigger on second click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I am using CSS and JS to animate a button [here](http://tst.eclipsecreative.ca/hobson/), the goal is when you click "Welcome" the button fades to "close" which it does, but once you click again I need it to fade back to welcome.

[Here is a jsfiddle of my current code that works (only one step)](http://jsfiddle.net/ePBVF/2/) as you see it on the [live link](http://tst.eclipsecreative.ca/hobson/)

[Here is a jsfiddle of a modified version where I tried to get it to work with a second click](http://jsfiddle.net/ePBVF/4/)

Thanks in advance! Or if someone has another (easier method) please fill me in.

Comment: Your fiddles are great, the invisible button is a cool touch ?

Comment: I don't see it the button to close here

Comment: Hey, if you read my description I link to the live demo twice:
http://tst.eclipsecreative.ca/hobson/ the fiddles are just for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#welcomebtn").click(function() {
  $("#welcomebtn img.top").toggleClass("transparent");
  return false;
});
```

You can do this to toggle the button back when the lightbox is closed:

```
$(".jquery-lightbox-overlay").click(function(){
    $("#welcomebtn img.top").toggleClass("transparent");
});
```

But do note that the user can click anywhere to close the lightbox.

Comment: then get rid of the line: `return false;`

Comment: thanks but then its back to the same issue I had before, you can see if you click on the button: http://tst.eclipsecreative.ca/hobson/ it will say "close" which is good but when you click "close" to close the lightbox it does not change back like it did before I removed return false;

Comment: So... what's happening is, the lightbox isn't closing because you clicked the close button. When you *open* it, it creates an overlay which will close the lightbox when you click on it. So, if you click where the button is, it's not the button that's getting closed, but the overlay.

Comment: I see you just updated your post. I have implemented this and the lightbox closing by clicking anywhere is no problem, but were still back to the issue of the button not fading back on the 2nd click. Im even fine with making both buttons disappear with the lightbox closing.

EDIT: Do you not want that second script to go: toggleClass("visible")...I tried that as well with no luck.